# Can 어떻게 돼요 be seen the polite way to say 뭐예요 ('what is it')?

Tags: polite

I have seen 어떻게 되다 used for asking politely about personal attributes:

> 성함이 어떻게 되세요? => What is your name?
>
> 아버님은 연세가 어떻게 되세요? => How old is your father?

But I have also seen examples like

> 오늘 환율은 어떻게 되지요? => What is today's exchange rate?
>
> 이 컴퓨터는 가격이 어떻게 되지요? => How much is this computer?

Sometimes when I am trying to politely ask what something is I say '뭡니까?' but I'm not sure I often hear native speakers say that. Is 어떻게 되다 a generally-usable way to ask politely what something is, or is it specific to certain situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, just like in English, people think it's more polite if you can say the same sentence using more (meaningless) words. 
For example, you can ask a person's name by

- Could you tell me your name?

rather than

- What is your name?

and the former is generally considered more polite.

The same goes here for Korean,

- 이름이 뭐야? (to someone in lower status/standing)
- 이름이 뭡니까? (in a formal, businesslike situation)
- 이름이 어떻게 되세요? (pretty polite)
- 이름이 어떻게 되시는지요? (even more polite)

Note that `되(-다)` verb here is very light, carrying almost no meaning (like verb `be`).

Also note that the bottom two sound quite awkward, since to the nouns (`이름`) do not correspond to the level of politeness from the verbs. `성함` or `존함` would be okay, as in OP's example.

Lastly, some argue that `이름(성함)이 어떻게 되세요(되시는지요)?` is ungrammatical, since here the speaker raises the **name** of the listener (the subject of the sentence), not the actual person. The point is that you must use `-시-` honorific tail only with human subject. From this perspective, you should ask `이름이 어떻게 돼요(됩니까)?` Still, a lot of people use `-시-` with a person's property in real life, especially in CS/CRM industry.

Answer (score 0):

I think '어떻게 되다' has nothing to do with politeness.
'뭐예요' is also polite exression because ~예요 has honorific meaning.

It is same expression of '어찌되다.'
See http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000212241&supid=kku000220865